# MySQL sort 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am trying to `sort` MySQL result from `qry_ledger_all_balance` and it's working fine, but the problem is I can only sort by `PaymentDate`.

I want to sort in the order of:

1. `PaymentDate` value
2. `Debit` value
3. `Credit` value

I am unable to do that. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Here is my Table Structure Sample.

```
+-----------------+-------+--------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|   PaymentCode   | Debit | Credit |     PaymentDate     |         Particular         |
+-----------------+-------+--------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| CTM-41700000008 | 25000 |      0 | 2017-05-15 17:27:28 | Token Money From Customer1 |
| CTM-41700000007 | 12000 |      0 | 2017-05-15 17:26:26 | Token Money From Customer2 |
| CRV-11700000166 | 15000 |      0 | 2016-05-15 17:57:01 | Customer1 Receipt Vourcher |
| EPV-21700000012 |     0 |    150 | 2017-05-15 14:23:26 | Cash Outflow               |
| EPV-21700000004 |     0 |   1110 | 2017-05-15 14:06:48 | Cash Outflow               |
| EAS-41700000001 |     0 |  10000 | 2017-05-15 12:27:47 | Employee Advance Salary    |
+-----------------+-------+--------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

Here is my query code in PHP

```
$branch_sql = "SELECT a.PaymentCode, a.Particular, a.Credit, a.Debit, 
Date(a.PaymentDate) AS PaymentDate, a.BranchID, a.CCode As RefPrint, 
a.RunningBalance, a.OpeningBalance, b.branchname FROM qry_ledger_all_balance AS a 
INNER JOIN tblbranches AS b 
ON a.BranchID = b.branchid 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.PaymentDate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '$Start_Date' AND
DATE_FORMAT(a.PaymentDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '$End_Date' 
ORDER BY a.PaymentDate ASC, a.Debit ASC, a.Credit ASC";
```

Comment: looks like you want to sort by date rather than datetime. try `order by date(a.paymentdate), ...`

Comment: So, you want to order by date, and then see all debits, then all credits?

Comment: @Jacobm001 Yes it's a cash ledger first order by date then all `debits` of that date then all `credits` of that date

Comment: The code you have shown us does what you describe as your objective, albeit very innefficiently. What you describe as your table structure is neither the structure of the tables you use in your query nor the output of the query.

Comment: @Rtra: Okay, I think my answer does what you need. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `order by` clause needs to be slightly more clever. Putting a case statement in your `order by` will let you create a group like sorting element.

```
SELECT 
  a.PaymentCode, a.Particular, a.Credit, a.Debit, 
  Date(a.PaymentDate) AS PaymentDate, a.BranchID, 
  a.CCode As RefPrint, a.RunningBalance, 
  a.OpeningBalance, b.branchname 
 FROM qry_ledger_all_balance AS a 
 INNER JOIN tblbranches AS b 
   ON a.BranchID = b.branchid 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.PaymentDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
   >= '$Start_Date' 
 AND DATE_FORMAT(a.PaymentDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
   <= '$End_Date' 
 ORDER BY 
  date(a.PaymentDate) ASC, 
  case 
    when a.Debit > 0 
      then 0
    else 1
  end ASC, 
  case 
    when a.Debit > 0 
      then a.Debit
    else a.Credit
  end ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I suspect you want

```
 ORDER BY DATE(a.PaymentDate), 
          CASE WHEN a.Debit > 0 THEN 1     /* nonzero debit */
               WHEN a.Credit > 0 THEN 2    /* zero debit, nonzero credit */
               ELSE 3 END,                 /* both zero, both nonzero */
          a.Debit, a.Credit
```

because if you don't use the `DATE()` function, MySQL will order by date *and* time.

By the way, your date selection criteria aren't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  This can cause serious performance problems when your tables get big.

Try this instead.

```
WHERE a.PaymentDate  >= '$Start_Date'
  AND a.PaymentDate  < '$End_Date' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(Notice the `<` and the extra day at the end of the range. That will include all records with `DATETIME` values anytime on the `$End_Date`. )

If you have an index on `a.PaymentDate` this will allow that index to be range-scanned.

Comment: Somebody will hassle you about SQL injection vulnerabilities. That's great, it means I don't have to.

Comment: Date sort works fine but the debit and credits won't sort properly